# Removing specific integers from columns in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

Here is what my current dataframe looks like:

```
Name <- c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George")
Loc1 <- c("001001", "001002", "001002", "002002")
Loc2 <- c("001002", "002002", "001002", "001001")
Loc3 <- c("002002", "001002", "001002", "001001")
dat <- data.frame(Name, Loc1, Loc2, Loc3)
dat
```

And this is my desired result:

```
Name <- c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George")
Loc1 <- c("11", "12", "12", "22")
Loc2 <- c("12", "22", "12", "11")
Loc3 <- c("22", "12", "12", "11")
result <- data.frame(Name, Loc1, Loc2, Loc3)
result
```

Note that the number remain the same, but I am looking for a way fro remove the "0" characters from multiple columns and leave behind other integers. I have tried using various incarnations of the strstring() and substr() functions for this, but seem to keep getting stuck because  "0" is not recognized as a character. It seems a fairly simple problem but I need some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

in order for this to work you need both `gsub` and a member of the apply family, like this:

```
Name <- c("John", "Paul", "Ringo", "George")
Loc1 <- c("001001", "001002", "001002", "002002")
Loc2 <- c("001002", "002002", "001002", "001001")
Loc3 <- c("002002", "001002", "001002", "001001")
dat <- data.frame(Name, Loc1, Loc2, Loc3)

data.frame(sapply(dat, function(x) {gsub("0", "", x)}))

# Name Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
# 1   John   11   12   22
# 2   Paul   12   22   12
# 3  Ringo   12   12   12
# 4 George   22   11   11
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy `gsub` over all columns except the first.

```
dat[-1] <- lapply(dat[-1], gsub, pattern = "0", replacement = "")
dat
#     Name Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
# 1   John   11   12   22
# 2   Paul   12   22   12
# 3  Ringo   12   12   12
# 4 George   22   11   11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
     mutate_at(vars(matches("Loc")), funs(str_replace_all(., "0", "")))
#    Name Loc1 Loc2 Loc3
#1   John   11   12   22
#2   Paul   12   22   12
#3  Ringo   12   12   12
#4 George   22   11   11
```